# Are private setters in C++/CX properties a thing?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Is it possible to create/design in a way to privately set a property but only expose the ability to get the properties to the consumers?

I've tackled a multiple inheritance property by making the base class wrapper a member of the concrete classes wrapper. I'd rather not allow someone to write over the base classes instance in the set of it's own property. But I can't seem to exclude `set` and set the base property and I can't make the `set` private.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
ConcreteClassWrapper(); // here I want to setup base class, i.e. give it a pointer to the actual C++ model I'm working with.

property BaseClassWrapper^ BaseClass 
{
    BaseClassWrapper^ get() { return baseClass; }

    // I want to avoid giving my consumers the ability to set this property.
    void set(BaseClassWrapper^ value) { baseClass= value; }
}

private:
    BaseClassWrapper^ baseClass; // Having a base class wrapper makes it easier on code writing.. i.e. I don't need to implement interfaces. I just want to use my C++ code in C# Microsoft GOD!!!
```

EDIT:

I'm an idiot, I can access the private member...

Answer (score 0):

This is just one answer... Still want to know why private setters arent' a thing

I just have to access my private member of my `ConcreteClassWrapper` and set the base class there. Then I can remove the `set` in the `BaseClassWrapper` property.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
property BaseClassWrapper^ BaseClass 
{
    BaseClassWrapper^ get() { return baseClass; }
    private:
      void set(BaseClassWrapper^ value) { baseClass= value; }
}
```

This is the way you write a private setter in a property. In the case of C++/CX, the property keyword is just a new keyword to allow C++/CX compiler to generate some C++ code, so the syntax for things like private, public, protected is the same.